# When install tailwind, styles from vite and css file still apply even though they are deleted

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I installed tailwind and other tools using `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer vite` as tailwind doc says

Configure tailwind.config.js

```
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
}
```

Add the Tailwind directives to index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And tailwind works, but old style from Vite still apply.
Example:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvzpM.png

Somehow i get dark background from vite example count. I deleted all files but they still apply.

Comment: possibly a browser cache issue? Chrome does this a lot

Comment: I tried in Firefox and brave, and it's the same.

Comment: Of course, what you can do is use the browser developer tools to determine where the styling is coming from

Comment: well, its says bg applied to :root and its  looks like this :root, [data-theme]. I no idea where the theme came from and how to disable it, but with daisyui I changed to light theme. Thanks for hint

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find clear solution, but cause in this case is theme applying to root. in dev tools it shows `:root, [data-theme]`. So I just change the theme to light theme in index.html I edit HTML tag`<html lang="en" data-theme="light">`.